# Commutivity of $A$ and $\sqrt{AA^*}$ in the proof of existence of compatible complex struture

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry

The following contents is in de Silva's Lectures on Symplectic geometry.

I can't understand the sentence of "Since $A$ commutes with $\sqrt{AA^*}$ "

Why these commute with each other?

Thank you in advance.

> >
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: Note that if $B$ commutes with $A^*A$, then $B$ commutes with $\sqrt{A^*A}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because $A$ is skew-symmetric, $A^*=-A$. So $B$ also diagonalizes $A$ (but with imaginary eigenvalues).

Comment: $B$ diagonalizes $A^2$ but why this implies that $B$ also diagonalizes $A$?

Comment: You are right, to be more precise, as $A$ commutes with $AA^*= -A^2$ you may choose $B$ to diagonalize $A$ and $AA^*$ simultaneously. Perhaps a more natural way is to first diagonalize $A$ (eigenvalues of the form $ i\lambda_j$) and then use the $B$ coming from that diagonalization for $AA^*$ and its square root (eigenvalues $|\lambda_j|$).